# Change alpha of image in java for method drawImage()

Tags: java, graphics, bufferedimage, alpha, drawimage

I'm trying to change the transparency of an image over time, and I'm doing this with the method `drawImage()` from `java.awt.Graphics`. I know there's a lot of different answers online about how to do this, but I can't find a one that is simple enough for me to understand and implement.

Let's just say I have a `BufferedImage` image, and I want to draw this image with a 50% opacity. How would I initialize `image` and what would I do to adjust the alpha level of the image when I draw it. It would be great if I could use the method `drawImage()` and do something with that to change the transparency of the image, but it's probably not that simple.

Answer (score 9):

Never tried it, but I think the basic code would be:

```
AlphaComposite ac = AlphaComposite.getInstance(AlphaComposite.SRC_OVER, alpha);
g2d.setComposite(ac);
g2d.drawImage(...);
```

Comment: I think that's a part of it but it still doesn't work. I initialized g2d and made `float alpha = 1f`, but it still doesn't work. Do I have to do something else?

Comment: use BufferedImage.createGraphics() instead of BufferedImage.getGraphics() since it returns type Graphics2D by default.

Answer (score 1):

Using image filter.

```
float[] scales = { 1f, 1f, 1f, 0.1f };
float[] offsets = new float[4];
RescaleOp rop = new RescaleOp(scales, offsets, null);
g2d.drawImage(buffimg, rop, 0, 0);
```

4th element in scales array is transparency, this value goes between 0 - 1

Answer by camickr will make the entire component apply the alpha including all inner components. But that will be much faster.

Warning: Use Image Filters with Care

ref: http://www.informit.com/articles/article.aspx?p=1013851&seqNum=2